# Selection of informative features using neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, reduce

The goal is to reduce the number of input parameters to the neural network, because it is assumed that some of them are not informative (little influence on the output values). I know that there are built-in function http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/processpca.html, but I need to perform reduction by using a neural network.

Is there a ready-made solution? If not, then we can tell something in this direction, and algorithm steps etc.

Comment: As far as I understand I need Recirculation Neural Networks? Is there a ready-made solution?

Comment: you can simply add L1 regularization in the first layer and it will force selection of the most important features. There are also plenty of well defined mathematical solutions, like optimal brain surgeon technique of removing weights which do not really contribute to final prediction which can be easily adapted to prune whole neurons. You do nod need any specific kind of neural net for this kind of task, no "recirculation nn" (whatever it is).

Comment: @lejlot , >it will force selection of the most important features.
Finally I have to show what perematry were uninformative and removed. It works this way (simply add L1 regularization in the first layer)?

And how can I learn from the values of the weights after training, some of them are informative, and which are not?

Comment: L1 regularization makes it profitable for the network to set "0" weights to uninformative parts, thus effectively removing them from the network, simple and clean as that :-) The only issue is that it is per-weight and not per neuron, but for many cases it should be just enough.